# How can I use the carotene functions?

Tags: opencv

I found [these functions](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/carotene) named *"carotene"*.

This is apparently a *low-level library containing optimized CPU routines that are useful for computer vision algorithms.*

I would like to try them. What are the steps I have to do to be able to use them (options in cmake, etc).

A very simple program using one of them for reference would help a lot too.

Edit

I am wondering if to use these functions I have to change (recompile) my current OpenCV installation that now is

```
Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.3.4)
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO
```

in the "custom HAL" option?

EDIT2:
After recompiling OpenCV, Carotene is on

```
Other third-party libraries:
    Custom HAL  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
```

Comment: looks like there is a WITH_CAROTENE flag in cmake: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L178 but Carotene is only usable with nvidia tegra ARM platforms? https://answers.opencv.org/question/124364/linking-error-carotene-opencv-32-on-arm/ I think once you compile with carotene, the original functions are replaced and you dont have to do anything further.

Comment: ok, works on RasPi too: "OpenCV contains NVIDIA Carotene — it implements HAL for ARMv7 and ARMv8 architectures and uses NEON instructions. OpenCV enables Carotene HAL if -DENABLE_NEON=ON is specified" https://learnopencv.com/build-and-install-opencv-4-for-raspberry-pi/amp/

Comment: @Micka I have a Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier machine :)

Comment: Thanks for the links. It seems one of my boards has carotene active while another one does not. I am going to check the libraries.